# FlickrNet and Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, flickr

I am trying to get the example code from http://flickrnet.codeplex.com running for Win Phone 7.1, I get an error for the `PhotosSearch()` method. I added `FlickrNet` from `NuGet`. Am I missing something? The error is as below.

```
Flickr flickr = new Flickr("6317d8e0db3a555288202fe04b4f4972");
PhotoSearchOptions options = new PhotoSearchOptions();
options.BoundaryBox = new BoundaryBox(-1.7, 54.9, -1.4, 55.2); // Roughly Newcastle upon Type, England
PhotoCollection photos = flickr.PhotosSearch(options);
foreach(Photo photo in photos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Photo \"{0}\" is at {1},{2}", photo.Title, photo.Latitude, photo.Longitude));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, I did manage to get it working.
I removed all libraries and added Flickr.net and Flickrnet WP7 and it worked.